# Add extra URL in front of PHP function for redirect - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I use a PHP function which gets the current URL for a WordPress plugin:

`$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));`

If I then add `$current_url` to a href link, it will redirect to the current page. However, I want to add another link in front of the redirect (in front of the PHP code).

So if you are on 
`test.com/page123`

I want it to redirect to :
`test.com/redirect/https://test.com/page123`

So I basically want to add `test.com/redirect/` in front of it.

How can I add this to the PHP code?

Comment: `$current_url = 'http://test.com/redirect/' . home_url(…);` …?

Comment: @CBroe That won't be added to the beginning of the redirect, so that doesn't work...

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by that. You said you are outputting a link yourself, and if you want to prepend something to the variable before you output it there, that would be the (/a) way to do it. If that doesn’t work for you, then you need to properly describe what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that there is a simpler way of doing this is to add something to the href. The href is: `href='$current_url'` you can change it to `href='$current_url redirect'`.

Then it would redirect to `currentdomain.com/currentpage/redirect`. `currentdomain.com/currentpage` is then your current page.